# Does Offset work in tables? (Excel-VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm have an Excel sheet with a table that performs Index/Match formula in VBA and copy the values into the table. The code is as below:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

  If Not Intersect(target, Me.ListObjects("ProjectEntry").ListColumns("Asset No").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then

   With Me.Range("ProjectEntry[Description]")
    .Formula = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX(DieMaster,MATCH(B4,DieMaster[Asset No],FALSE),2)),"""",INDEX(DieMaster,MATCH(B4,DieMaster[Asset No],FALSE),2))"
    .Value = .Value
   End With

  End If

End Sub
```

I found that this code although works, will execute on all cells in the table. Now I want it to only execute in my selected row. Example, if I perform a change in A5, I want the code to execute in row 5 only.

I have tried using Offset as it worked for me in Excel when data is not in a table. Using the code below:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

 If Not Intersect(target, Me.ListObjects("ProjectEntry").ListColumns("Asset No").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then

  With target.Offset(0, 1)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX(DieMaster,MATCH(rc1,DieMaster[Asset No],FALSE),2)),"""",INDEX(DieMaster,MATCH(rc1,DieMaster[Asset No],FALSE),2))"
    .Value = .Value
  End With

 End If

End Sub
```

However it doesn't seem to work. Does this mean that Offset does not work in table? If not, is there another way?

Comment: (a) I just did a very simplified test using `Target.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=5"` and it worked.  So I think it is going to be something to do with the formula itself. (b) What do you mean by "However it doesn't seem to work." - just that it gives the wrong values?  (I notice your original formula matches data in column B, but your revised code tries to match based on column A - was that intentional?)

Comment: Add one line to your code: `MsgBox "Target = " & target.Address`. You might place it before the `If` or before the `With`. In the former case you will know if your event fires, in the latter where the formula is being inserted.

Comment: @YowE3K  when I said it doesn't work it means that no data appear in B5 when I keyed in data in A5.Also when I typed in value in B5 and then key in data in A5, B5 becomes blank again. I don't think it's due to the formula coz the original works. All I did was modify from the original the Offset function, change to FormulaR1C1 and change the formula to read rc1 instead of reading the cell.

Comment: @Variatus I used your msgbox trick on before with statement and found that value was inserted straight into A5... a quick change from rc1 into rc2 fixes that problem. :p thanks.

Comment: @hjh93 But you also changed your formula to use `MATCH(rc1` (i.e. `MATCH(A4` if the row was row 4) instead of `MATCH(B4` - are you sure that isn't causing an error?  Oops - I see you noticed that when you replied to Variatus.

Comment: @hjh93 I think you might be misunderstanding R1C1 notation - `RC1` is the equivalent of `$A4` in A1 notation.  `R` means current row, `R[-3]` means 3 rows before the current row, `R6` means the 6th row (i.e. `$6` in A1 notation), and similarly `C` means current column, `C[4]` means the 4th column to the right of the current column, and `C7` means column 7 (i.e. `$G` in A1 notation).  And "current" in those examples refers to the cell **in which the formula exists**, not the `ActiveCell`, or `Target` or `Selection`.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst using `RC2` fixes your problem, you are *far* better off using `RC[-1]`. If you move the table or insert a column to to the left of it, the code will break using absolute references, but not using relative ones.

You are also better off using the `IFERROR()` function rather than `IF(ISNA())` as it results in a formula that avoids repetition, and is half the length:

```
With Target.Offset(0, 1)
  .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX(DieMaster,MATCH(RC[-1],DieMaster[Asset No],0),2),"""")"
  .Value = .Value
End With
```

However, the best way to refresh the edited row only, is to do the calculations in VBA and write the results to the sheet.

The following code does this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("ProjectEntry[Asset No]")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  Dim Ä As Excel.Application: Set Ä = Excel.Application
  Dim varValue As Variant

  With Ä.Range("DieMaster").ListObject.ListColumns
    varValue = Ä.Index(.Item(2).DataBodyRange, Ä.Match(Target.Value2, Ä.Range("DieMaster[Asset No]"), 0))
  End With
  Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = IIf(IsError(varValue), vbNullString, varValue)

End Sub
```

Note the usage of `Application.` instead of `WorksheetFunction.` to access the worksheet functions. This, coupled with the use of a Variant type variable, allows us to trap the error that occurs when the match fails.

Comment: For using `Ä` as a variable name .. +1.  Have you tried use `“A”` - that's a lot of fun too.  (Actually, the +1 was mainly for the recommendation to use `RC[-1]`.)

Comment: @YowE3K Hey, I remember now! I *did* try that a long time ago :)